# Palavras cruzadas vertical

Tags: python

**Problema:** Escreve uma função chamada find_word_vertical que aceita uma lista de 2 dimensões de caracteres e, uma string como argumentos de input. Esta função procura nas colunas da lista de duas dimensões para encontrar uma palavra igual à palavra de input. Se uma igualdade é encontrada, a função retorna uma lista contendo o index da linha e o index da coluna em que o principio da palavra encontrada começa, caso contrário retorna o valor None.

Por exemplo, com os seguintes inputs:

```
crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'
find_word_vertical(crosswords,word)
```

Então a função deve retornar:

```
[1,0]
```

**A minha solução:**

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    num = len(crosswords)
    joinner = ''
    w = str()
    vert_cross = list()
    for i in range(num):
        w = joinner.join(vert_cross)
        if word in w:
            for let in w:
                if let == word[0]:
                    row_ind = w.find(let)
                    col_ind = i-1
                    return [row_ind, col_ind]
        for j in range(num):
            vert_cross.append(crosswords[j][i])
```

A saída dá-me *None*, mas a resposta correta seria *[0, 1]*

O que é que está mal no meu código?

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está funcionando para a palavra 'cat', mas não funcionará caso a palavra procura esteja na última coluna ('mkt', por exemplo) porque sua comparação está sendo feita na iteração seguinte da coluna (a primeira apenas appenda o conteúdo)

Segue uma sugestão de solução:

```
crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'

def find_word_vertical(cw,w):
    for i in range(len(cw)):
        wstr = ''.join([cw[j][i] for j in range(len(cw))])
        if wstr.find(w) != -1: 
            return (i,wstr.find(w))
    return (-1,-1)

print find_word_vertical(crosswords,word)
```

Aproveitando, como dica, existe a lib pprint que para esse caso ajuda a visualização no interpretador:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(crosswords)
[['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'],
 ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'],
 ['a', 'c', 'a', 't'],
 ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
>>>
```